# Swiper creating blank slide when i swipe one direction, but not the other

Tags: swiper.js

Im currently having some problems with react-id-swiper, and i couldn't find any information regarding this issue.

My slider is working if i'm only swiping to the left, but when i try swiping the other direction it creates an empty slide at -1436px, which doesn't happen when i swipe to the left, then it only goes to -718px.

When i remove all the CSS it acts the same way, only working in one direction.

These are my parameters

```
const params = {
    loop: true,
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        type: 'bullets',
        clickable: true
    }
};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: would you be able to add a jsFiddle to demonstrate the issue?